# Error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint data types match

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Not sure what else to check/do. I made sure the foreign key data type matches (char(36)) and I ensured the foreign key statement uses the correct syntax

Running this script i get error 1215

```
USE addm;
CREATE  TABLE `addm`.`notificationResource` (
`notificationId` CHAR(36) NOT NULL ,
`resourceId` CHAR(36) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`notificationId`, `resourceId`) ,
INDEX `fk_notificationResource_notification_idx` (`notificationId` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_notificationResource_resource_idx` (`resourceId` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_notificationResource_notification`
FOREIGN KEY (`notificationId` )
REFERENCES `addm`.`notification` (`id` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_notificationResource_resource`
FOREIGN KEY (`resourceId` )
REFERENCES `addm`.`resource` (`resourceId` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
commit;
```

Parent Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `resource` (
`resourceId` char(36) NOT NULL,
`resourceName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`resourceData` longblob,
PRIMARY KEY (`resourceId`),
UNIQUE KEY `resourceName_UNIQUE` (`resourceName`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `notification` (
`notificationType` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
`aborted` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`attempts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`content` longblob,
`recordDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`sent` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
`sentDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`subject` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`fromUser_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`toUser_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`attachmentName` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`attachmentData` longblob,
`category` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
`read` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
`locked` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `FK2D45DD0B7F734EAD` (`toUser_id`),
KEY `FK2D45DD0BE62E629E` (`fromUser_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK2D45DD0B7F734EAD` FOREIGN KEY (`toUser_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK2D45DD0BE62E629E` FOREIGN KEY (`fromUser_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

Comment: I think column CHARACTER SET is different.
`id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,

Comment: that was it. Can you make it an answer and i'll select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think column CHARACTER SET is different. id char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
change CHARACTER SET

Comment: Again thanks for this. It was working on another's database and it makes since as to why now.